# Classes and headers in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, class, header-files

Why Xcode gives me "Redefinition of Console" error?
Should not be the same name in the header and cpp ?

Here is the code:

ui.cpp:

```
#include "ui.h"
    class Console {
    public:
    void run() {
        puts("Hello my friend!");

    }
};
```

ui.h:

```
class Console {
public:
    void run();
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ui.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Console c;
    c.run();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Should not be the same name in the header and cpp?

No, the .cpp file should have the implementations, not the declaration.  This would look like:

```
#include "ui.h"

void Console::run() {
    puts("Hello my friend!");
}
```

Note that you also probably should [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your .h file to prevent them from being included multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Classes are defined in header files. The `.cpp` should contain the implementation of the functions, not the class definition.

ui.cpp should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>    /* for puts */
#include "ui.h"

void Console::run() {
    puts("Hello my friend!");
}
```

If you’re learning C++, try a tutorial like http://www.learncpp.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Because you redefined it. Literally right there in your code.

To define one of its member functions, you do *just that*, without repeating the class's definition:

```
#include "ui.h"

void Console::run()
{
   puts("Hello my friend!");
}
```